# How can I set 'always make image public' whenever I upload image to S3 AWS?

Tags: amazon-s3

Let's suppose if I am uploading an image to AWS S3 (manually from the console), and I would like everyone to view it. Currently, I upload an image, go to actions, and make it public. This process repeats for every image. How can I prevent myself doing the last step (i.e. not making the image public everytime, it will be checked by-default)

So, every image I upload, I would just copy it's URL, without doing anything else. It would be made public by-default.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that if you add the following policy to your bucket:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [{
    "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Principal": {
      "AWS": "*"
    },
    "Action": [ "s3:GetObject" ],
    "Resource": [ "arn:aws:s3:::MY_BUCKET_NAME/*" ]
  }]
}
```

all uploaded files will become public by default - taken from [here](https://schier.co/blog/how-to-make-files-uploaded-to-s3-default-to-public).

Answer (score 0):

You can add change rules or go to properties of bucket you can disable block public access to that bucket.